Your client does not have permission to get URL
When I try to send an update notification to the Web Search Indexing API (https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish), I receive this:
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  
<meta charset=utf-8>\n  
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  
<title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>\n  
<style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  
<a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  
<p><b>403.</b> <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s an error.</ins>\n  
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/v3/urlNotifications:publish</code> from this server.  <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s all we know.</ins>\n

But I'm pretty sure it worked yesterday. I checked my account in Google Cloud, it was not banned or anything. What could it be?

Thanks to this great answer here, I had to disable IPv6:
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -p

